# "Grid" table in an insert statement in SQL Windows

Tags: guptateamdeveloper

How to identify a "Grid column" in an insert statement as they are dynamically created I'm not able to refere these.  When I try to add columns in the grid they appare with the correct title, but still not able to refere in an INSERT.  The "Grid" is loaded from an .xls.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can refer with hashtag with column index:
tblData#1, tblData#2, tblData#3, tblData#4, ...etc.

Where "tblData" is Child Table Name and #1, #2,... are column indexes.

Example:

```
Call SqlPrepareAndExecute( hSql, 'insert into TABLE(id, name) values(:tblData#1, :tblData#2)' )
```

Comment: I tried this  !!CB!! 70
Set sSave =
  'INSERT INTO produkt(kom_nummer,produkt_type,reg_no,appl_metode,dose,styrke )
  VALUES (:grid#1,:grid#2,:grid#3,:grid#4,:grid#5,:grid#6)'
 Return FALSE
and got this

Comment: I will, but how do I do this, I looked all over?  Only as a comment I can "accept" here, but if elsewhere pls. show where